# How do I reference a previous financial value in pinescript so that I can calculate the growth rate of that value?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, quantitative-finance

I am attempting to calculate the change in earnings per share on a continual basis (in order to later calculate the growth rate). I currently have:

```py
eps = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "EARNINGS_PER_SHARE_DILUTED", "FY")
```

I would like to be able to retrieve the prior reporting period's value for `EARNINGS_PER_SHARE_DILUTED` so I can calculate the change in EPS. Is there a way to reference the prior reporting period's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `var` variable to store the last financial data in memory.

In the below example, I used the `security()` call with `barmerge.gaps_on` so that it would only update my variables once when there is new data available. Once there is new data, simply update your "last" and "current" variables.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var float current_financial_val = na
var float last_financial_val = na

eps = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "EARNINGS_PER_SHARE_DILUTED", "FY")
eps_gap = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "EARNINGS_PER_SHARE_DILUTED", "FY", barmerge.gaps_on)

if (not na(eps_gap))    // New financial data
    last_financial_val := current_financial_val
    current_financial_val := eps_gap

plot(eps, color=color.white)
plot(current_financial_val, color=color.green)
plot(last_financial_val, color=color.red)
```

Note: You don't need the `eps` variable. I just left it there so you can see what is going on.

Comment: Ok, I think that makes sense. Does that then turn it in to a kind of array that can be plotted along x-y axis?

Comment: It will be of type `series float`. You can plot it as I did in my example.

Comment: That's great! Thanks! Can I use a variation of the script to reference 5 and 10 years ago? (So that I could track eps growth rate changes for 10,5 and 1 years). If so, how would I modify the script?

Comment: I'm not sure if that much historical data is available on Tradingview. You just need to check for the date with the built-in variables like `year`, `month` etc. and store it in another `var` variable if the date matches with your desired date.